# How to integrate a floating action button between two components in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am designing a twitter timeline where I am going to design "add a profile " floatingActionButton between two Components.I also don't which these two components are?

Comment: Generally when you ask question like this without providing more context, you wouldn't get any answer. You can improve your answer by showing us what you have done (mockups, wireframing, code), and what is it you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Generally, but not always I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the elements needs to be positioned relative with a fixed height so you can position the floating action button absolutely.

For example, specify a height for your header, position relative, then position your FAB absolutely using a negative bottom.

See this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/01pl0497nl

As far as the components to use, you are probably trying to position it on the [seam](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/principles.html#) between two pieces of [Paper](https://material-ui-next.com/api/paper/).

Comment: can I do this using material-ui version "0.20.0";

Comment: Yeah, I believe you can.  The primary differences are that FloatingActionButton is its own component in v0.x and styles must be defined inline or via className prop, rather than the JSS approach for v1.

Comment: So, how to do above problem using material-ui v0.X?